# jacobson radical and frattini

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

suppose that $L$ is nilpotent leibniz algebra.why $J(L)=\Phi(L)$.

$J(L)$ is jacobson radical.and $\Phi(L)$is frattini ideal of $L$.and we know that if $L$ is nilpotent $L^2=\Phi(L)$.

thanks your help

Comment: @ Crostul :I know that $\Phi(L)\subset F(L)$ and I think $F(L)\subset J(L)$.since every ideal is subalgebra.then $\Phi(L)\subset J(L)$.and I cant prove converse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nilpotent Leibniz algebra L every maximal subalgebra of L is an ideal of L (see D.W.Barnes, Some theorems on Leibniz algebras, Comm. In Alg. 39. , 2011, 2463-2472).

Comment: :I appreciate your help.